# Setting UINavigationController Bar title in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set my navigation bar title but no matter where I set the title it will not show. I have the background color set and that change is applied, just not the title. Please advise.

```
  import UIKit

  class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController{
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.themeDarkGray()
          navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.themeDarkGray()
          navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]  // Title's text color
          self.title = "Title Here"

      }
  }
```

Comment: I have. I can see the view controller with the new nav color, just not the title.

Comment: Try `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Title here" ` ?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 that was it! Thanks! If you post as answer I will accept as answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Title here"`.

It should work! :)

Comment: This sets the navigation title of the parent controller for me.

Answer (score 2):

if you set custom NavBar then:

```
Self.navigationBar.pushItem(UINavigationItem(title: "Title"), animated: true)
```